# Double quote and less characters (">) create a problem with listings

Tags: listings, punctuation, verbatim

I don't know how to fix this problem, when I use `">` in a listings I see a weird double `>` as result.

See this example, where the following section of my article:

```
De esta forma si el título ingresado por el astrónomo es \textit{Stars survey}, el resultado en el \textit{resource descriptor} será \code{<resource schema="stars\_survey">}.
```

Get the following result:

[image]

And when I use simple quotes there's no problem:

[image]

So, how can I fix the problem? **I want to be able to write a `">` in the listings!**

BTW, I declared my `code` command like this:

```
\newcommand\code[1]{
  \tikz[baseline=(s.base)]{
    \node(s)[fill=gray!20,draw=gray]{\texttt{#1}};
  }
}
```

Comment: `">` is a babel shorthand for spanish (goes for », as you found out). You can use `\shorthandoff{">}` before your listings code and then re-enable it later with `\shorthandon{">}`. Alternatively you could for `"\textgreater`.

Comment: You could also look into [`listings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) or other packages that really treat their argument verbatim. Then you can write `"stars_survey"` directly and don't need to escape the `_` as in `"stars\_survey"`. Verbatim is tricky, so it is possible that you can't get exactly what you want here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments